# Python type hints: typing.Mapping vs. typing.Dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I'm working on a python3 project where we use the `typing` module type hints throughout.

It seems that we use `typing.Dict` and `typing.Mapping` pretty much interchangeably.

Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: dicts are a kind of mapping

Comment: `dict` is a more specific kind of mapping, it's like a sequence vs a list

Comment: `Dict`s are mutable & a specific implementation. `Mapping` is an interface and is immutable.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Managed to answer this myself.

`typing.Dict` should be used to indicate a literal `dict` type with support for element type hinting i.e. `Dict[bytes, str]`

`typing.Mapping` is an object which defines the `__getitem__,__len__,__iter__` magic methods

`typing.MutableMapping` is an object which defines same as Mapping but with `__setitem__,__delitem__` magic methods as well.

typing.Mapping et al. are based on the abc types in [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes)

Comment: Rule of a thumb: expect generic types, return specific types. This gives users of your functions and classes the biggest flexibility and safety.

Comment: One more difference. `Dict` is invariant, `Mapping` is covariant. It's important when e.g. you have a function receiving `Dict[A,B]` and try to pass `Dict[A,C]` where `C` is a subtype of `B`. You will get typing error which can be avoided by using `Mapping[A,B]`, See https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/#covariant-contravariant-and-invariant.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Besides the rule, if a function preprocess on the inputs, should I use `Dict` as both input and output types? Receiving a `MutableMapping ` and then returns a `Dict` seems a bit inconvenient in this case ...

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Hint about generic types is good.. but in this case which is more generic, Mapping or Dict?

Comment: @hubatish Mapping is more generic because there are more classes than `Dict` that implement the 3 magic methods that `Mapping` stands for.

Comment: I believe `Mapping` is only covariant over it's value, not it's key.

Answer (score 14):

As suggested by the [official python (3.11) documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict) `typing.Dict` is useful for annotating return types. To annotate arguments it is preferred to use an abstract collection type such as `Mapping`.

Also, `typing.Dict` has been deprecated since version 3.9. in favor of `dict`.

Comment: Although the official docs do not explicitly indicate that `typing.Dict`/`dict` (or any specific implementation of an ABC) is useful for annotating a return type, the explicit wording regarding annotating arguments does seem to infer so. However, I recommend doing the same for return types. The reason for doing so is that by annotating the return type as an ABC, you (as the implementer) are free to change the specific implementation that you return, without causing a breaking change, because there is no need to change the annotated return type.

Comment: @ChuckDaniels No. Using your logic, annotating all return types with [`Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any) would give you the most freedom. Such code will act as no inner change will ever break any user code, while in fact the opposite is true.

Comment: @Jeyekomon, I'm not sure I understand your point. Perhaps my wording was imprecise. When I said, "without causing a breaking change," I was referring to keeping the type checker happy. In other words, for example, by using `Mapping` as my type hint for the return type, rather than `Dict`/`dict`, I am indicating to the user that I am returning something that implements the `Mapping` interface, meaning that the value I return can be _any_ implementation of the interface. Therefore, I am free to change the implementation under the covers without causing the type checker to complain.

Comment: @ChuckDaniels I understand your point, my explanation has probably been too brief. It's does need some time and explanation to get it. Type `Mapping` is a more general type than type `Dict`. Using more general return types has two aspects: 1) They give you more options to change your code without needing to change the return type. 2) They give less information about the returned object and ways to interact with it to the user. By doing that, you are basically preferring your comfort over the user.

Comment: @ChuckDaniels An example: Some mappings provide a method `pop`, some not. All dicts do. If the return type is `Mapping`, then the user cannot pop from your returned objects. Well, he technically can, since the annotation is just for your future comfort and you are actually currently returning only dicts. But if he did it, he risks that you change the returned type to some other mapping without the popping ability and break his code. By not providing a return type as specific as possible you needlessly limit the user. Software versioning is generally used to handle breaking changes.