# Why is typing.Mapping not a Protocol?

Tags: python

As described [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#predefined-protocols), some built-in generic types are `Protocols`. This means that as long as they implement certain methods, type-checkers will mark them as being compatible with the type:

> If a class defines a suitable `__iter__` method, mypy understands that it implements the `iterable` protocol and is compatible with `Iterable[T]`.

So why is `Mapping` not a protocol?

It clearly *feels* like it should be one, as evidenced by [this well up-voted SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52487800/2071807):

> `typing.Mapping` is an object which defines the `__getitem__`,`__len__`,`__iter__` magic methods

If it *were* one, I could pass things which behave like mappings into function which require a mapping, but doing that is not allowed:

```py
from typing import Mapping


class IntMapping:

    def __init__(self):
        self._int_map = {}

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._int_map)

    def __setitem__(self, key: int, value: int):
        self._int_map[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key: int):
        return self._int_map[key]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._int_map)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._int_map)

    def __contains__(self, item: int):
        return item in self._int_map

    def keys(self):
        return self._int_map.keys()

    def items(self):
        return self._int_map.items()

    def values(self):
        return self._int_map.values()

    def get(self, key: int, default: int) -> int:
        return self._int_map.get(key, default)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self == other

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self != other


x: Mapping = IntMapping()  # Type checkers don't like this
```

*Shout-out to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71299170/2071807) for pointing me to the link about protocols)*

Comment: Note that I found the stuff about Protocols thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71299170/2071807) on another question of mine. This question gets better to the heart of why I asked that other one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be deliberate, and basically boils down to 'we think that type is too complex to be a protocol.' See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#changes-in-the-typing-module.

Note that you can get this effect by having your own class extend `abc.Mapping`

Comment: This answer led me to some really interesting reading about `typing.Protocol` and the reason for its introduction. That's exactly what I posted this bounty for. I'll award to the best answer once the bounty is close to expiration.

Comment: Can you provide a source to the argument explicitly against making `Mapping` a `Protocol`? That PEP 544 section merely lists those classes that _were_ made to inherit from `Protocol`. It does not say anything about those that do not. Who said it was _"too complex"_ and where? I could not find an actual answer for this anywhere.

Comment: Nevermind, I found a discussion about this in the old `python/typing` issue thread about protocols, starting with [this](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/11#issuecomment-383458683) question. I think this should be part of the answer here since you did not give any source for that claim.