# What is the proper type annotation for any object that can be unpacked with the ** operator?

Tags: python, types, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a function that looks like this:

```
from pandas import Series
def my_function(unpackable: dict | Series) -> None:
    {**unpackable}
```

I would actually like to type hint for any object that can be unpacked with the `**` operator while excluding those that cannot. I thought about `typing.Mapping`, but it appears `isinstance(Series({"a": 1}), Mapping)` is `False`.

What is the proper type hint for any object that can be unpacked with the `**` operator in Python?

Comment: I would think `Iterable`.

Comment: `Mapping` (or an equivalent `Protocol`) is correct -- I don't think `isinstance` can necessarily infer at runtime whether something can be treated as a `Mapping` though.

Comment: (Unless of course you explicitly subclass `Mapping`, which makes it easy -- but my impression based on my limited experience with pandas is that pandas is not interested in making typechecking easy.)

Comment: It's also possible to register subtypes of ABCs like `Mapping` IIRC.

Comment: @Samwise `Mapping` is indeed a good practical suggestion, just keep in mind that it is **not actually a `Protocol`**. See my answer below for details.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "or an equivalent Protocol".  I was thinking you'd have to define your own protocol that defines an interface that's equivalent to `Mapping`, similar to what you did in your answer, if you wanted your annotation to work with mappings that don't actually inherit `Mapping`.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

In most cases `collections.abc.Mapping[K, V]` will be just fine.

The widest possible valid annotation is a (generic) [protocol](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544) implementing the `__getitem__` and `keys` methods:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable, Hashable
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

K = TypeVar("K", bound=Hashable)
V = TypeVar("V", covariant=True)


class DoubleStarUnpackable(Protocol[K, V]):
    def keys(self) -> Iterable[K]: ...
    def __getitem__(self, key: K, /) -> V: ...
```

## Digging deeper

This topic is not as straightforward as you might think at first glance. To find out what an appropriate type annotation for *"unpackable"* objects is, we need to dig into a few different sources.

---

### What do you actually *need* for unpacking?

Since [PEP 448](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/) the unpacking operators `*` and `**` can be used in multiple different circumstances. The restriction on the `**` operand type is explicitly mentioned in the [official Expressions documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

> A double asterisk `**` denotes dictionary unpacking. Its operand must be a [mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping).

The term *mapping* is further defined as a

> container object that supports arbitrary key lookups and implements the methods specified in [...] `collections.abc.Mapping` [...].

To see what the specific methods of a collections ABC are, I find it most helpful to check [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes).

But what may be surprising (at least it was for me), is that **not all of those are actually necessary** for unpacking to work at runtime.<sup>1</sup> By doing a bit of experimentation, we can see which methods are necessary. It turns out that all you need is a **`__getitem__`** and a **`keys`** implementation.

Minimal example:

```py
class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, item: str) -> int:
        if item != "a":
            raise KeyError
        return 1

    def keys(self) -> str:
        return "a"
```

Demo:

```py
def f(a: int) -> None:
    print(f"{a=}")


f(**Foo())

print({**Foo()})
```

Output:

```
a=1
{'a': 1}
```

You will notice that this also passes `mypy --strict` without errors.

But as soon as you remove either of those two methods, you will get an error both from `mypy` and at runtime.

---

### So how do we annotate it?

It turns out that the good people at [`python/typeshed`](https://github.com/python/typeshed) are also aware of this (no surprise here) and have defined a protocol for just that and called it [`SupportsKeysAndGetItem`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/274f449edce829201ef63da2e566497b28d3d97c/stdlib/_typeshed/__init__.pyi#L120):

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

_KT = TypeVar("_KT")
_VT_co = TypeVar("_VT_co", covariant=True)


class SupportsKeysAndGetItem(Protocol[_KT, _VT_co]):
    def keys(self) -> Iterable[_KT]: ...
    def __getitem__(self, __key: _KT) -> _VT_co: ...
```

This obviously works just fine with our silly `Foo` class and we can use it to annotate your function like this:

```py
def my_function(unpackable: SupportsKeysAndGetItem[str, int]) -> None:
    unpacked = {**unpackable}
    print(f"{unpacked=}")


my_function(Foo())  # unpacked={'a': 1}
```

Again, `mypy` accepts this code without errors.

We can actually see that `mypy` uses this exact protocol from the typeshed to check, if something is *"unpackable"* or not. If we omit either the `keys` or the `__getitem__` method from `Foo` and try to do `{**Foo()}`, the error message from `mypy` will tell us:

```
List item 0 has incompatible type "Foo"; expected "SupportsKeysAndGetItem[<nothing>, <nothing>]"
```

(Not sure what lists have to do with this, but the relevant bit here is that it tells us it expects something that implements the `SupportsKeysAndGetItem` protocol.)

---

### Why not just use `Mapping`?

You could do that of course and in most situations that is just fine and is exactly how I would annotate something that is supposed to be unpacked at some point. But there are still two relevant caveats to keep in mind.

#### `Mapping` is *not* a protocol!

Unlike other collections abstract base classes such as `Iterable`, `Container` or `Reversible`, the `collections.abc.Mapping` class ist **not actually a protocol**. The classes that *are* protocols are all listed [here in PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#changes-in-the-typing-module) as well as [here in the `mypy` documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#predefined-protocols-reference).

The consequence is that structural subtyping will not work.

Even if I wrote a class `Foo` that implements *all* the `Mapping` methods (i.e. `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, `__len__`, as well as the inherited `__contains__`, `keys`, `items`, `values`, `get`, `__eq__`, and `__ne__`), a type checker will *still* complain, if I tried to do `m: Mapping = Foo()`.

Only nominal subtyping (i.e. inheriting from `Mapping`) would make this work. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299591/why-is-typing-mapping-not-a-protocol) is another Stack Overflow question about this exact topic.

#### `pandas.Series` is *unpackable*, but not a `Mapping` subtype

Since you brought up the `Series` class in your question, I am using it here as a stand-in for any class that you could use for unpacking.

Annotating your function like this would not allow a `Series` argument to be passed:

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping

def my_function(unpackable: Mapping) -> None: ...
```

For example `mypy` would complain, if you did `my_function(pd.Series())`:

```
Argument 1 to "my_function" has incompatible type "Series[Any]"; expected "Mapping[Any, Any]"
```

So you would have to resort to specifically defining a union for the annotation, like Anton Petrov suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76267801).

But then what if someone would like to pass something that is *neither* a `Mapping` subclass, *nor* a `pd.Series`, but still *unpackable*?

This is basically the argument for making your function parameter type annotations **as wide as possible**.

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup> At least in the current CPython implementation. I could not find specific documentation for this.

Answer (score 1):

The only requirement for the unpackable type is to follow the `Mapping` protocol, but it doesn't mean it should be inherited from `Mapping`.

So `Mapping` should be enough in most cases, but if you want to be more descriptive, and considering you care about `Series` specifically, you could create `Unpackable` alias:

```py
Unpackable = Union[Mapping, Series]
```

<s>But, actually, `mypy` will be happy if you provide `Series` for the `Mapping` type, so it's just a matter of what seems more readable to you.</s>

Comment: Note that `Mapping` is **not** actually a `Protocol` (as confusing as that may be). Therefore `mypy` will **not** accept a `Series` object, when the annotation says `Mapping` (even though that would make sense). See my answer for details. The practical suggestion of defining a type alias for the union of `Mapping` and `Series` is good though.

Comment: Interesting, `mypy` doesn't complain about `mapping: Mapping = Series({"a": 1})` when I run it locally. Perhaps, I'm missing something? But thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the pandas stubs and it just does not check `Series` at all? At least for me with `mypy==1.3.0` and `pandas-stubs==1.5.2.230105` that does produce the expected error.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I was missing `pandas-stubs`, now it does produce the error. Thanks for noticing!